Compilation Issue with type
I'm creating a type as below but not able to compile
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Item FORCE AS OBJECT (
   id                      NUMBER
   
  STATIC FUNCTION getobject RETURN item
);

Getting error:
[Error] Compilation (24: 3): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "STATIC" when expecting one of the following:

   := ) , not null default external character


There's a comma missing between NUMBER and STATIC.
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Item FORCE AS OBJECT
  2  (
  3     id NUMBER,
  4     STATIC FUNCTION getobject
  5        RETURN item
  6  );
  7  /

Type created.

SQL>

